# How to cache/store the access token and reuse it later until it expires

Tags: sharepoint-online

The response body of access token API of  SharePoint  contains

```
"token_type": "Bearer","expires_in": "86399","not_before": "1590557783","expires_on": "1590644483"
```

these parameters along with the  bearer token. Since this   bearer token is required in  all other SharePoint rest API calls, so is there a way to cache/store this  bearer token till it expires and  reuse this  token  so that I do not have to call the access token API again  and  again for  all other API calls  where bearer token is required. I am using this  in a  Java based application.

Answer (score 0):

MS provided a library for Jave that could help to store and cache the token, you may have  a try it:

- [Custom token cache serialization in MSAL for Java](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-java-token-cache-serialization)

And here are some demos:

- https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/blob/4715fcd4f9/src/samples/cache/TokenCacheAspect.java

BR